# feedback on the page layout and ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, node.js, pug

Need some feedback and guidance on the page design and Ajax call.
Just fyi, the application is nodejs based.

The intial Webpage is a table where initally only the first column is displayed.
Something like this -

```
   Category       SubCategories              

   Cars           
   Trucks
   SUV
```

When user selects Cars, then it should populate the SubCategories column with - Ford, Honda etc. So the page should display like this -

```
   Category       SubCategories                
   Cars  >        Ford
   Trucks         Honda
   SUV            Fiat
```

HTML View

```
<body>
    <div id="category-container">      
        <h1></h1>
        <p id="sub1" class="subheading">Select a category</p>    
        <div style="margin:20px" class="container">
          <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>                
                <th style="width:180px">Category</th>
                <th style="width:200px">SubCategory</th>                
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div id="myid"><a href="/playground/:0">Electronics</a></div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div id="myid"><a href="/playground/:1">Real Estate</a></div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>   
    </div>
</body>
```

When user clicks Cars, I am planning to create an ajax call and get the data from the server. The ajax response is going to be populated in the second column.

Question - The above table is not a form. Does the table has to be a form to make an Ajax call?

Here is the initial jquery code which eventually I am expecting to make an Ajax call but when I click those table items it's not executing the alert pop-up's. Can anybody help me with the jquery code for making an Ajax call ?

When I run this code in jsfiddle its hitting the alert statement not sure why its not doing the same when I run it locally.

JQuery Code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {             
    $(".myid").click(function () {  
         alert("Element selected"); 
    });                               
});
```

Comment: how did you include the script?

Comment: Thanks man. My fault. The jade template was not correctly formed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether you have properly mentioned the jquery CDN link or path to jquery file in script tag

First of all for ajax submission it need not be a form, you can trigger an AJAX onclick, onselect, onchange etc. 
On clicking cars, the data returned from server can be html data, and you can just populate data to a success element.

eg.

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: destinationUrl,
            data: content,
            success: function(data) {
            $('#successDiv').html(data); // here you have your html data
            }
        });
```

where successDiv is the div or element where data is to be populated